# Inconsistent yaml indentation and validity

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to write a yaml file: a manifest for kubernetes.
However, depending on my editor (visual code or vim) or my linter (yamllint python package or [this](https://www.yamllint.com/) website), I end up with a valid or invalid yaml file. For example this snippet is invalid for the website and valid for yamllint. It is also automatically indented like that by vim90 but not by visual code:

```
initContainers:
  - name: s3-sync-init
```

The opposite is true for this snippet:

```
initContainers:
- name: s3-sync-init
```

I read that there are several versions of yaml, could it be what causes this inconsistency ? How can I know which yaml version kubernetes is using ? How can I know which version of yaml is being parsed by the linter or the website or any of my code editor ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both versions are valid YAML that parse identically (so long as neither version is tab-indented), though I can't quite language-lawyer it from the [YAML 1.2.2 spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/).  In a Kubernetes context I frequently see the inner list indented as in the first example, but that's merely a common style more than a hard-and-fast rule, I'm sure I've written the second form as well.

Answer (score 0):

In principle there are no different versions of YAML. But some parsers are incomplete and/or follow the outdated (since 2009) YAML 1.1 specification. Is incomplete, and should not be trusted. Just try the valid YAML `[ 1, 2 ]: sequences are allowed as keys` and see how it mangles the key to a string. This is to be expected because the tool is dependent on pyyaml, which only handles a subset of the outdated YAML 1.1 specification.

Within the specification there is room for different representations of the same data. The main difference is between block style (as in your examples) and flow style ( more like JSON). But even within each of those you have variations of expressing the same.

In block style the data of nested collections needs to be indented, but not necessarily the sequence element indicator (`-`, the dash). In both your examples you have mapping within a sequence within a mapping. In the first example the data of the sequence (which itself is againa a mapping), is indented two positions to the root level mappinig, which forces the dash to be left aligned with the beginning of the mapping's key (as there has to be space between the dash and the element). In the second example the sequence data is indented four positions which allows (but not necessitates) the dash to be moved along to the right.

You could also have formatted it as:

```
initContainers:
 -  name: s3-sync-init
```

or

```
initContainers:
-   name: s3-sync-init
```

If in doubt I recommend using `ruamel.yaml` to load and dump such data (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
initContainers:
  - name: s3-sync-init
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
initContainers:
  - name: s3-sync-init
```

You can try out the formats in your question and my answer, all of them load to the same Python data structure and are valid YAML. You will need to play with the `.indent()` parameters to get the other results as output, but each of those can also be created from the loaded data (of themselves or the others).